# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 on Visual studio Mac C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, linker

I'm new to programming and wanted to try out VS Code for C++ development. I'm getting this error and I can't find a solution online how to fix:

> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_main", referenced from: implicit entry/start for main executable ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


    long FactorielleMod(int n){
        const int c= 1000000007;
        if (n == 1 ){
            return n;
        } else {
            return ((n % c)*FactorielleMod(n-1)) % c;
        }
    }
```

Basically a code to compute the factorial function.
Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: There must be another error message before, is it complaining about a missing `main()` function?

Comment: Here is the whole errors:
deRunnerFile.cpp -o tempCodeRunnerFile && "/Users/Usr/Desktop/Bureau-MBP/M2/S1/C++/projekt/helloworld/"tempCodeRunnerFile
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: [Edit] your quesiton to put additional information please.

Comment: You mist define a function `int main()` as entry point for your executable program, that's what the error says.

Comment: You're right, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Exit code 1 means that an error happened. It is probably because you have no `main` function, which is required for every C++ program. You need something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


long FactorielleMod(int n){
    const int c= 1000000007;
    if (n == 1 ){
        return n;
    } else {
        return ((n % c)*FactorielleMod(n-1)) % c;
    }
}

int main(){
    int a;
    cin>>a;
    cout<<FactorielleMod(a);
    return 0;
}
```

It will print you factorial function of inputted integer.

Comment: No, the code won't calculate a factorial. Look twice please.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ it does address the question asked, however.